# Embedded broker assumes Logback is SL4J binding

Tags: qpid

I am very new to QPid, so bear with me. Starting an embedded browser for some integration tests, I ran into this line in `org.apache.qpid.server.Broker.startup(BrokerOptions)`:

```
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger =
                (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
```

It throws a `ClassCastException` as it presumes that I am using Logback, which I am not and cannot.

Can anyone advise how I can work around this?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: It looks as through the class was removed in 6.1.0 https://github.com/apache/qpid-broker-j/tree/6.1.0/broker-core/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/server

Comment: Downgrading from 6.1.3 to 6.0.7 alas doesn't improve matters, as the result of `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` is not a `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` and provokes a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: I can't find a org.apache.qpid.server.Broker class in 6.1.3. Aren't you using a pre 6.1 release already? What exactly are you including?

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems still exists in 6.1.x. ( https://github.com/apache/qpid-broker-j/blob/6.1.x/broker/src/main/java/org/apache/qpid/server/Broker.java

This is actually preventing from starting broker via https://github.com/daknin/qpid-maven-plugin. (